# How to get a one product information by ID from wcapi?

Tags: python, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to get a one product information by Id in wcapi([Module page](https://pypi.org/project/WooCommerce/)).I use this code But dont work :/ and get all product information

```
from woocommerce import API
wcapi = API()
response = wcapi.get('products',params={'id':776}).json()
```

Comment: print(wcapi.get("products/794").json())

Comment: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#retrieve-a-product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other mentioned the API works as below:

`/wp-json/wc/v3/products/<id>`

So use the API as mentioned in the documentation and your code should be like below:

```
from woocommerce import API
wcapi = API()
response = wcapi.get("products/794").json()
```

Read more about the output [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#create-a-product).

It's always a good idea to stick with documentation.